# Accessing chain id and genesis hash from the Substrate runtime during extrinsic execution

Tags: substrate, parity-io

I am using Substrate's latest stable `pre-v2.0-3e65111`
I wanted to access the chain id or genesis hash from the Substrate runtime while processing an extrinsic (I am accepting signed payloads and trying to ensure the payloads were targeted to the right chain). Is it possible to access them? (I know I can do that with polkadot-js)
I see trait `CheckGenesis` but don't see how I can use it to genesis hash? (`new` results in empty vector).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the implementation for `CheckGenesis` here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L1417

```
impl<T: Trait + Send + Sync> SignedExtension for CheckGenesis<T> {
    type AccountId = T::AccountId;
    type Call = <T as Trait>::Call;
    type AdditionalSigned = T::Hash;
    type DispatchInfo = DispatchInfo;
    type Pre = ();
    const IDENTIFIER: &'static str = "CheckGenesis";

    fn additional_signed(&self) -> Result<Self::AdditionalSigned, TransactionValidityError> {
        Ok(<Module<T>>::block_hash(T::BlockNumber::zero()))
    }
}
```

From this, you should be able to see that you can access the genesis hash by calling:

```
frame_system::Module::<T>::block_hash(T::BlockNumber::zero());
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks. It works for me. I used `let hash = <system::Module<T>>::block_hash(T::BlockNumber::from(0))` (not using `T::BlockNumber::zero()` as it was asking me to import another trait). Now `hash` implements `AsRef<[u8]>` so i got the byte slice with `hash.as_ref()`.